# Can't clearTimer in async interval

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I'm trying to modify an implementation of some TensorFlow face detection algorithms using Java.
At the moment, I've added a button that properly stops/starts the video streaming from my camera. Also, when the video is playing, I detect the faces on it every 100ms with an async interval.

The problem appears when I Stop and then restart the video streaming because multiple detections are generated. I'm assuming it's related to the interval considering that I print the detections and the interval var to console and there are more than one detections in the same interval and the interval doesn't reset to zero after clearInterval(DetTim) when the video gets paused.

My code is as follows (I'm omitting a load of models and the StartVideo function):

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video')
const PlayButton = document.getElementById('play-button')
var DetTim = null

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)

  if (!video.paused){
    DetTim = setInterval(async () => {
      console.log(DetTim)
      const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new 
      faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
      canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)

    }, 100)
  } else {
    clearInterval(DetTim)
    console.log(DetTim)
  }
})


PlayButton.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play()
    e.target.textContent = '▌ ▌'
} else {
    video.pause()
    e.target.textContent = '▶'
  }
})
```

Also, here are some screenshots related to the problem. In the first shot, the code works properly as it has just been initialized. In the second one, multiple detections (blue rectangles) have been drawn over the canvas after multiple starts/stops clicks.

[First Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF0qY.png)

[Second Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s1Kx.png)

Comment: Does it even ever go into that `else` branch? I don't see why it would - because I don't see how `video.paused` would ever be true in that handler function ...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event: _"The play event is fired when the paused property is changed from true to false, as a result of the play method, or the autoplay attribute."_

Comment: You're right. It doesn't. But before I tried to put the clearInterval within the click when the video gets paused, and the DetTim remains the same. How should I implement it correctly?

Comment: I would either handle both in the click event, or both in the play and pause event. Mixing both, does not sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430717/cant-cleartimer-in-async-interval/70441983#comment124513067_70430717):

> I would either handle both in the click event, or both in the play and pause event. Mixing both, does not sound like a good idea.

I ended up handling the click event within the play event and it solved the issue.